# Osmbonuspack : marker's onDoubleTap function not working when adding the markers in RadiusMarkerClusterer

Tags: java, android, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I created a custom marker where I overrode onDoubleTap Method, which worked as I expected, but when I added my custom Marker to RadiusMarkerClusterer, my onDoubleTap function didn't work as I wanted and it didn't be called when I double-tapped on the marker in the Map View

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap: Event=>"+e.getX()+", "+e.getY()+"Marker =>"+this.getPosition().toString());
    boolean touched = hitTest(e, mapView);
    if (touched){
        Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap: ");
        mSlidePanelListner.onDoubleTap(mapView);
    }
    return touched;
}
```

Comment: ***RadiusMarkerClusterer*** extends from ***MarkerClusterer***; ***MarkerClusterer*** extends from ***Overlay*** of ***OsmDroid SDK***. However, since these extended classes don't override `Overlay.onDoubleTap()` method, it returns false. It should be overridden so that ***OverlayManager*** can handle every overlay's double-tap event. The same issue with ***FolderOverlay*** class from ***OsmDroid SDK***. See https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now solved on the master branch.